# REST WS with Interface

Tags: java, web-services, rest, interface

I'm trying to implement a REST WS. The following code works ok:

```
@Path("/MyRest")
@WebService
public class MyService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response test(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        String str = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"id\":\"" + id + "\"}";
        return Response.status(200).entity(str).build();
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WSRest</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now i'm trying to do it with an Interface. The interface would be like follows, I guess:

```
@Path("/MyRest")
@WebService
public interface IService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response test(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

And now the WS implementation would be like this, right?:

```
public class MyService implements IService{
@Override
public Response test(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    String str = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"id\":\"" + id + "\"}";
    return Response.status(200).entity(str).build();
}
}
```

I'm getting "`HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception`" when I try to "run" it again :/
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Full exception:**

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: The rest of the exception stack trace probably explains what the problem is. Read it, and post it. But my reasoning would be: assume you have 4 implementations of this interface, which one should Jersey choose?

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace from your server logs?

Comment: Posted full stacktrace.

Comment: Annotations are not inherited in Java. I also don't know how Jersey does its component scanning to find resource handlers. It's possible Jersey doesn't find any `@WebService` implementation classes and therefore fails to startup.

Comment: @JB Nizet. I understand that, where should I point to that interface then? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Jersey enough to answer. But I don't see what you gain by using an interface for Jersey services, and by not annotating the concrete class.

Comment: @JBNizet Supposingly, I should use an interface if I'm doing a WS. It's a "good programming practice" :P

Comment: No, it's not. Nobody will ever use this interface. And it will never have more than one implementation. It's useless. And even if you want it, that doesn't prevent you from annotating the concrete class.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks to all :)

Comment: You should not use annotation `@WebService` in your REST class since that annotation is specifically for SOAP web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a web method using an interface:

Web service implementation:

```
@Path("/WS")
@WebService
public class WebService implements IWebService {

@Override
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/Login")
public Response Login(JSONObject data) {
    //stuff here
}
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IWebService {

@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/Login")
public Response Login(JSONObject data);

}
```